# A way to access all child addresses from HD wallet xpub

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

Is it possible to retrieve all the infinite addresses of a HD wallet from just its parent public key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet

> Master public key
>
> Certain types of deterministic wallet (BIP0032, Armory, Coinkite and Coinb.in ) additionally allow for the complete separation of private and public key creation for greater security and convenience. In this model a server can be set up to only know the Master Public Key (MPK) of a particular deterministic wallet. This allows the server to create as many public keys as is necessary for receiving funds, but a compromise of the MPK will not allow an attacker to spend from the wallet.

So yes, if that is correct, with a BIP32 wallet you can create all the HD addresses from the master public key. The method is explained a little in [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#Public_parent_key_rarr_public_child_key).

There is a complication from choice of hardened or non-hardened keys etc. See [ELI5: What's the difference between a child-key and a hardened child-key in BIP32](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37488/13866)