# Understanding signrawtransactionwithwallet and the Transaction Signing Process

Tags: wallet, bip32-hd-wallets, output-script-descriptors

I would like to understand all the advantages of a descriptor wallet.

I comprehend that the wallet safeguards the user by not exposing the private key. However, when I use `bitcoin-cli listdescriptors true`, I can identify the xprv (hardened), thereby enabling the generation of the entire tree of private keys. Doesn't this pose a greater risk?

The next [problem](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37488/eli5-whats-the-difference-between-a-child-key-and-a-hardened-child-key-in-bip3) that the descriptor is going to resolve is the problem with xpub and not hardened private key.

How does the wallet currently sign transactions? I'm aware of the command `signrawtransactionwithwallet`, but what occurs in the background? Is the derivation calculated every time to obtain the private key and sign the transaction?